# Firebase orderbypriority not working

Tags: android, firebase

I am currently using Firebase as a database and am trying to use the orderbypriority to sort my firebase entries. But I am having a problem with orderbypriority. When I use orderbypriority on the firebase reference to query my database, it does not return the data in the order of each element's priority. Here is my code that I am using:

```
Firebase answersRef = new Firebase("/Questions/ModeratorQuestions/General/" + question.getKey() + "/Answers");
answersRef.orderByPriority().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
});
```

Here is how my database is setup within firebase

```
-Questions
    -ModeratorQuestions
        -General
            -QuestionIdNumber
                -Answers
                    -Answer 1 (With priority of 0)
                    -Answer 2 (With priority of 1)
                    -Answer 3 (With priority of 2)
```

A snapshot can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGAZh.jpg).

Here is the output I get from the dataSnapshot when I try to query the url specified above in my code (I took out the project name from the url).

```
{ key = Answers, value = {Douglas_Comer={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, Sophie_Dee={.priority=1.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Yes={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, No={.priority=1.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Go_on_a_shopping_spree_at_the_mall={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, Donate_it_to_charity={.priority=3.0, .value=0}, Stocks={.priority=4.0, .value=0}, Go_to_Walmart_I'll_figure_out_the_rest_when_I_get_there={.priority=2.0, .value=0}, DANCE={.priority=0.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Yes={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, Love_is_Dead={.priority=2.0, .value=0}, No={.priority=1.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {three_landmines={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, 1,000_non-venomous_snakes={.priority=0.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {have_free,_coach-seating,_air_travel_once_a_month={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, own_a_yacht={.priority=0.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Valentine's={.priority=3.0, .value=0}, Thanksgiving={.priority=2.0, .value=0}, Other={.priority=4.0, .value=0}, Halloween={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, Christmas={.priority=0.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Bread={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, Tortillas={.priority=3.0, .value=0}, Pasta={.priority=2.0, .value=0}, Rice={.priority=1.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {fight_your_crush={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, fight_a_bear_cub={.priority=1.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Happy_relationship={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, Eligible_Bachelor={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION={.priority=2.0, .value=0}, Focused_on_beautiful_Science={.priority=4.0, .value=0}, I_have_no_idea_what_I'm_doing={.priority=3.0, .value=0}} }
{ key = Answers, value = {Apples={.priority=0.0, .value=0}, Bananas={.priority=1.0, .value=0}, Oranges={.priority=2.0, .value=0}} }
```

As you can see, most of them are not order by their priority. I don't understand why though. If someone could help me on what I am doing wrong, it would be appreciated. I can also answer questions if you need more information.

Comment: Can you copy/paste a brief snapshot of your Firebase data structure into the question?

Comment: @Jay No I need at least 10 reputation to post images, which I don't have but can find the image at http://imgur.com/y5ydfoz

Comment: You shouldn't post an image, but the actual text. You can easily get that from your Firebase dashboard by pressing the Export button.

Comment: What Frank said. Copy and paste the text structure or use the export button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in a Map have no defined order. But the items are retrieved in the correct order from Firebase, which you can verify if you loop over them:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(child.getValue());
    }
}
```

See for the same question, but then for iOS: [Issue displaying array of image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703181/issue-displaying-array-of-image-from-url/35708683#35708683)